# Ansible can't read from host_vars

Tags: ansible

I have a problem

`"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'str object' has no attribute 'node1'", 'failed': True}`

In Hosts : 

`[test]
192.168.1.1`

In /etc/ansible/host_vars/192.168.1.1

`nginx:
- { node1: "192.168.2.1" }`

In /etc/ansible/roles/nginx/templates/site.j2

`server {{ item.node1 }}:80;`

Help me please why ansible can't read a host_vars files and put variable in template/ file. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Your `/etc/ansible/host_vars/192.168.1.1` should be

```
nginx:
  node1: "192.168.2.1"
```